# Is it possible to call a previously defined method from within a method of the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to overwrite a method and still fallback to the original method (given no superclass is involved)?

```
def User
  def method
    # do some original stuff
  end
  def method
    # do some new stuff
    call_the_original :method
  end
end
```

Hopefully, my specific example will make my meaning more clear.

Using activestorage `has_one_attached :avatar` in a User model adds a setter method. I want to do some stuff when this setter is called, but I still want the original method to run.

```
class User 
  has_one_attached :avatar
  # According to the source (see references) this mixes in the following setter method 
  def avatar=(attachable)
    # do activestorage stuff 
  end 

  # I want to add some custom functions to this, before still running "do activestorage
  # stuff". I could copy, paste and edit the entire function. But out of interest, 
  # I wondered if a more elegant solution exists. 
  def avatar=(attachable)
    # do my stuff
    super(attachable)
  end
end
```

`super` obviously does not work because User is not inheriting from anything in which `avatar=()` is defined.

I could create e.g. `MasterUser` class containing `has_one_attached` and from which `User` inherits, but this seems overkill for just this particular case.

I could submit to a `custom_avatar_method=(attachable)` which calls `avatar=(attachable)`.

But with this question what I'm really interested in is whether there a way to call a previously defined method from a method of the same name?

**References**:

- [`#has_one_attached` source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/96ac7e4cdee004bcd19cb63b3e3396329e3b39ed/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/model.rb#L34-L47)

Comment: Active Storage should really be defining its method in a parent module, so that `super` works for this use case. PR welcome :)

Comment: Thanks @matthewd. I've opened an issue, feel free to jump in! https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33690. As it turns out, this did not solve my `set a filename` need - quite a common use case I would think. Activestorage and `StringIO.original_filename` are doing some strange things behind the scenes!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [`alias_method`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method) to access the previous definition here:

```
class User 
  def avatar=(attachable)
    # do activestorage stuff 
  end 
  alias_method :original_avatar=, :avatar=

  def avatar=(attachable)
    # do my stuff
    self.original_avatar=(attachable)
  end
end
```

Comment: very cool! exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. I will give it a test. Thanks @jagdeep

Comment: Use `self.` for calling your original method as it is an assignment.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I believe that's only needed if you use the assignment operator. If you'll use a method call you can leave it out. eg. `original_avatar=(attachable)` or `self.original_avatar = attachable`

Comment: thanks @JagdeepSingh, works perfectly to solve my question. Unfortunately, this direction did not solve my underlying Activestorage issue, but never mind!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is saving the old method inside a variable before defining the new method with the same name. Then call the variable from inside the newly defined method:

```
class User 
  def avatar=(attachable)
    # do activestorage stuff 
  end 

  instance_method(:avatar=).tap do |avatar_eq|
    define_method(:avatar=) do |attachable|
      # do my stuff
      avatar_eq.bind(self).call(attachable)
    end
  end
end
```

In the above example `define_method(:avatar=)` has to be used, since a regular `def avatar=` wont let you access the `avatar_eq` variable.

The code is somewhat more complicated than [JagdeepSinghs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51962405/3982562), but leaves the class less cluttered with methods. The old method is no longer defined and thus can no longer be called by itself.

**References**:

- [`Module#instance_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-instance_method) to get the previously defined method
- [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) to namespace a variable to a small portion of the class definition
- [`Module#define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-define_method) to define the new method with the same name
- [`UnboundMethod#bind`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind) to bind the unbound method to the current `User` instance
- [`Method#call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-call) to call the bound previously defined method

Comment: thanks @Johan, this is a great answer, and useful references!